# SQL query for Figuring counts by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

whats a good way to join 1-12 in a column to a bunch of counts by month?... in SQL

```
SELECT
    months???,
    count(whatever1) count1,
    count(whatever2) count2
FROM
    months????
    LEFT JOIN whatever1 ON
        month(whatever1.Date) = months???.monthid
    LEFT JOIN whatever2 ON
        month(whatever2.Date) = months???.monthid
GROUP BY
    months???
```

something that would end up like

```
"month","whatever1count","whatever2count"
1,null,5
2,null,3
3,null,null
4,2,3
5,36,73
6,2,null
7,45,944
8,null,12
9,1467,3
10,null,2
11,3,25
12,4,null
```

edit- basically where is a slick way to get my months list/table/whatever

Comment: Which database are you using - MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL?  They all differ in subtle ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many ways... one that worked well for me across many applications at a previous job was to build a table of timeframes.

```
id - Year - Month   - StartStamp            - End Stamp  
1  - 2008 - January - 1/1/2008 00:00:00.000 - 1/31/2008 23:59:59.999
```

Then you can just join against the timeframes table where your date field is between startstamp and endstamp.

This makes it easy to pull a certain time period, or all time periods...

Yours could be simpler, with just 12 records (i.e. 1 - January) and joining on DATEPART(m,DateColumn)

```
select mon.monthNumber, mon.monthName, 
       count(a.*) as count1, count(b.*) as count2
from months mon
left join whatever1 a on DATEPART(m,a.Date) = mon.monthNumber
left join whatever2 b on DATEPART(m,b.Date) = mon.monthNumber
group by mon.monthNumber, mon.monthName
```

You could also do the month thing ad-hoc, like so:

```
select mon.monthNumber, mon.monthName, 
       count(a.*) as count1, count(b.*) as count2
from (
   select 1 as monthNumber, 'January' as monthName
   union
   select 2 as monthNumber, 'February' as monthName
   union
   select 3 as monthNumber, 'March' as monthName
   union
   ......etc.....
) mon
left join whatever1 a on DATEPART(m,a.Date) = mon.monthNumber
left join whatever2 b on DATEPART(m,b.Date) = mon.monthNumber
group by mon.monthNumber, mon.monthName
```

Comment: Was kinda hopin for a slick way to just maybe explicitly define a temp table or something, but that would def work

Comment: This is a very good approach. If you create such table with a record per day in a reasonable time frame, you can do all kinds of weird stuff, like accounting for the non-standard calendars like broadcast or manufacturing/accounting, or group associated records by weekdays, weekends and holidays.

Comment: Is there a query-only solution to this problem or is creating a table really necessary?

Comment: @payling you can create a table in the query.. i.e. `join (select 1 as month union select 2 as month union select 3 as month ........) months on ....`

Comment: I decided to create a table like you suggested. I  originally thought creating a table for a single query would be a waste, but now that I have the table I have thought of several uses for it.  Thanks Fosco

Answer (score 4):

> basically where is a slick way to get
>   my months list/table/whatever

You can use a recursive cte to build a list of months.

```
;with Months(MonthNum) as
(
  select 1 MonthNum
  union all
  select MonthNum+1
  from Months
  where MonthNum < 12 
)

-- Your query goes here
select * 
from Months
```