# Can I force a T-SQL query with "Group By" to return rows which have no data?

Tags: t-sql, group-by

Sorry if this title of this question isn't any good; I'm not sure I can succinctly describe it, so here's the verbose version:

I'm trying to generate a report, and I'm actually not sure if what I want to do can be entirely done within a SQL statement.  The output I want would be something like this:

```
Product X
 January:  1 sold
 February : 0 sold

Product Y
 January : 0 sold
 February: 1 sold
```

Here's the basic SQL statement (which, btw, has to run against SQL Server 2000 and 2008--don't ask):

```
SELECT p.productName, 
       SUM(s.salesID) AS numSold, 
       MONTH(s.salesDate) AS monthSold
FROM sales s 
LEFT JOIN products p ON s.productID = p.productID
WHERE s.saleDate > '1/1/2011'
AND s.saleDate < '2/28/2011'
GROUP BY p.productName
ORDER BY p.productName, MONTH(s.salesDate)
```

The problem, as I understand it, is this SQL statement (rightly) doesn't return a row for the combination of month+sales for any month where there were no sales.  But in order to make actually outputting this data easy, what I really need is for the statement to return some value (ideally 0, but it doesn't have to be) for any product+month that contains no data.

So, what the query is returning now is:

```
productX January 1
ProductY February 1
```

...and what I would like it to return is this:

```
productX January 1
productX February 0
productY January 0
productY February 1
```

It kind of seems like this is something I should be able to do.  I tried something like this:

```
SELECT p.productName, 
       ISNULL(SUM(s.salesID),-100) AS numSold, 
       MONTH(s.salesDate) AS monthSold
```

...but, perhaps predictably, that didn't work.

Help?  (-;

Comment: Can we make an assumption that a sale will happen at least once a month for any product? That is, is it possible to ask for a date range with no sales *at all*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this recent question/answer: [SQL query for Figuring counts by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115945/sql-query-for-figuring-counts-by-month/6115991#6115991)

If you had a table of months, you could use that as your base table.  You'll get a record for every month.

Comment: Thanks.  See note below!  (-;

Answer (score 1):

I've seen situations where you can assume something happens at least once in the grouped reporting period

So, making an assumption that at least one sale will happen at least once a month for any product, you can pull out the month and year and generate a sequence to then LEFT JOIN against for the combined sales.

This may not work in all situations (eg group per day) but seems reasonable to assume you sell at least one thing per month...

Also, wouldn't it be COUNT not SUM?

```
SELECT
    p.productName, 
    COUNT(s.salesID) AS numSold, 
    series.aMonth AS monthSold,
    series.aYear AS yearSold
FROM
   (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        MONTH(salesDate) AS aMonth, YEAR(salesDate) AS aYear
    FROM sales
    WHERE saleDate > '1/1/2011'
    AND saleDate < '2/28/2011'
   ) series
   LEFT JOIN
   sales s ON series.aMonth = MONTH(s.salesDate) AND series.aYear = YEAR(s.salesDate) 
   LEFT JOIN
   products p ON s.productID = p.productID
GROUP BY
   p.productName, series.aMonth, series.aYear
ORDER BY
   p.productName, series.aMonth, series.aYear
```

This is Ok for SQL Server 2000+ too

Comment: So since I posted this, I got basically these same two answers elsewhere.  Option 1:  create a db table of dates.  Option 2:  create a "dates" table on the fly in the query.  Both are pretty nice solutions, but I think I may actually go with option 1, since I may also want to record other data against dates (e.g. "minUserID", "minSalesID", etc).  So thanks very much to you both.

Answer (score 0):

First time "answering" one of my own questions, so apologies if I screw this up, but...

@gbn and @Fosco both provided workable solutions, as I mentioned in my comment to @gbn's post.  They are:

1. Create a calendar table in your database, and reference that
2. Create a "calendar" table on the fly, either by using what @Fosco suggests, or something "sexier", like CTE (which I can't use, because CTE was introduced in SQL Server 2005).

So I think I've got what I need.  Hope this helps somebody else as well.

Comment: As your "answer" just summarises the other two and doesn't add anything new not sure why you aren't just accepting one of those?

Comment: because...I don't know what I'm doing?  I said up front I might screw this up.  (-;  I thought the person asking the question had to officially stamp the question as "answered", and I thought this was the only way to do it.  I didn't see a way to pick one of the comments as the official answer.  Also, both are perfectly good solutions, depending on need, so I wasn't sure it would make sense to pick just one.

Comment: You would administer your official stamp of approval by ticking the green tick to the left of an answer. This marks it as answered and boosts the rep of the answerer by 15 points.

Comment: Okay, my bad.  I picked @Fosco's, since that's the solution I used.